# 2 forms, and one email template. second form won't send

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, forms

I am trying to make 2 forms. 1 simple contact form, 2 only for email.

I want to use magentos email system (contact email) so i am using if else in the email template.

My second form template wont send. I get the "could not send email"

most likely some little typo or something. can you help?

Here are the code

Contact form template (standard magento)

```
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
<div class="page-title" style="margin-left: 2%;">
    <h1><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Kontakt IFP') ?></h1>
</div>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <h2 class="legend"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Kontaktformular') ?></h2>
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li class="fields">
                <div class="field" style="padding-right: 1%;">
                    <label for="name" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->helper('contacts')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div> &nbsp;
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->helper('contacts')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="telephone"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone') ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="text" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="wide">
                <label for="comment" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <textarea style="width: 100%;" name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?>" class="required-entry input-text" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <p class="required"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
        <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', true);
//]]>
</script>
```

Second form template(custom)should only contain email field

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li class="fields">
                <div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="1" />
                    <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email') ?>"  class="input-text required-entry validate-email" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>


        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
        <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Afmeld') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Afmeld') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Email template

```
{{if data.custom}}
    E-mail: {{var data.email}} :  Skal fjernes fra mail liste
{{else}}
    Navn: {{var data.name}}
E-mail: {{var data.email}}
Telefon: {{var data.telephone}}

Besked: {{var data.comment}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: what is this function work `onsubmit="return custom_submit()"`

Comment: it was just somehting i tried to get it to work, just ignore that

Comment: where are you set this `data.custom` variable?

Comment: its a hidden input in second form. <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="1" />

Comment: email sending code?

Comment: Do i have to make that, if Im using magentos own? if yes, how and where? :)

Comment: but when you are adding the addition field you have to set variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38571/discussion-between-patrick-knudsen-and-qaisar-satti).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `name` and `commen` fields as  **hidden**

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li class="fields">
                <div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="1" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="test" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="comment" value="test" />
                    <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email') ?>"  class="input-text required-entry validate-email" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>


        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
        <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Afmeld') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Afmeld') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That way it will be validaded! ;) You are gold Qaisar!